# R pattern to modify arguments passed to generic function

Tags: r, oop

I have a generic function called `foo`. It operates differently on the classes `bar` and `baz` but there is some shared pre-processing that needs to only be done once. What is the idiomatic R way of carrying this out?

In my silly example below, I want to multiply the object being passed to the generic by 10. Yet when the method is called, the original value is printed to the console. I have read the language definition and know that the below pattern does not work. My question is: Where or how should I handle shared processing of generic arguments before calling the method?

```
a <- structure(1:5, class="bar")
b <- structure(6:10, class="baz")

foo <- function(x) {
  x <- x * 10 # where should shared preprocessing go?
  UseMethod("foo")
}

foo.bar <- function(x) {
  cat("Foo!", x)
}

foo.baz <- function(x) {
  cat("Baz!", x)
}

# does not propagate the operations carried out `foo`
foo(a)
foo(b)
```

Comment: Even if not elegant, I would just choose the obvious path and retype the preprocessing part in both `foo.bar` and `foo.baz`. Alternatively, define a function that does the common part (without exporting it): `.preprocess<-function(x) #do stuff` and then `foo.bar<-function(x) {x<-.preprocess(x);#do other stuff}` and the same for `foo.baz`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1) Layer foo on top of actual generic** Change `foo` to perform the preliminary code and invoke `foo_` a new generic as shown.  Rename `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` to `foo_.bar` and `foo_.baz` respectively so that we are left with (have also added newlines to the example):

```
foo <- function(x) {
    x <- x * 10
    foo_(x)
}

foo_ <- function(x) UseMethod("foo_")

foo_.bar <- function(x) cat("Foo!", x, "\n")
foo_.baz <- function(x) cat("Baz!", x, "\n")
```

Now test it out:

```
a <- structure(1:5, class="bar")
b <- structure(6:10, class="baz")

foo(a)
## Foo! 10 20 30 40 50
foo(b)
## Baz! 60 70 80 90 100
```

For an example of this in a widely used package see the source of [dplyr::mutate](https://github.com/cran/dplyr/blob/master/R/manip.r#L143)

**2) NextMethod** Another way would be to give every object a class vector of two classes with `"foo"` made a subclass of `"bar"` in the case of `a` and of `"baz"` in the case of `b`.  Then use `NextMethod`.  Solution (1) seems simpler and it may seem weird that `"foo"` is a subclass of both `"bar"` and `"baz"` but here is an example of this one just in case:

```
foo <- function(x) UseMethod("foo")

foo.foo <- function(x) {
    x <- x * 10
    NextMethod()
}
foo.bar <- function(x) cat("Foo!", x, "\n")
foo.baz <- function(x) cat("Baz!", x, "\n")
```

Test it noting that we have changed the definitions of `a` and `b` so that they work with this approach:

```
a <- structure(1:5, class= c("foo", "bar"))
b <- structure(6:10, class = c("foo", "baz"))

foo(a)
## Foo! 10 20 30 40 50
foo(b)
## Baz! 60 70 80 90 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, still using the `NextMethod()` trick but hiding the extra class. We create an object just to dispatch to the PREPROCESS class

```r
a <- structure(1:5, class="bar")
b <- structure(6:10, class="baz")


foo <- function(x) {
  PREPROCESS <- structure(NA, class = c("PREPROCESS", .class2(x)))
  UseMethod("foo", PREPROCESS)
}

foo.PREPROCESS <- function(x) {
  x <- x * 10
  NextMethod()
}

foo.bar <- function(x) {
  cat("Foo!", x)
}

foo.baz <- function(x) {
  cat("Baz!", x)
}

foo(a)
#> Foo! 10 20 30 40 50
foo(b)
#> Baz! 60 70 80 90 100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A caveat is that now `foo(a)` and `foo.bar(a)` don't return the same thing, which is surprising, so I wouldn't do this for a user facing function. This applies to the other solution too.