# How to use R's S3-classes together with parameters?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I fear I get something really wrong. The basics are from [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) 
and a basic (minimal) example is understood (I think) and working:

```
fun.default <- function(x) { # you could add further fun.class1 (works)...
  print("default")
  return(x[1] + x[2])
}

my_fun <- function(x) {
  print("my_fun")
  print(x)
  res <- UseMethod("fun", x)
  print(res)
  print("END my_fun...")
  return(res)
}
x <- c(1, 2)
my_fun(x)
```

However, if I want to add parameters, something goes really wrong. Form the link above:

> Once UseMethod has found the correct method, it’s invoked in a special
>   way. Rather than creating a new evaluation environment, it uses the
>   environment of the current function call (the call to the generic), so
>   any assignments or evaluations that were made before the call to
>   UseMethod will be accessible to the method.

I tried all variants I could think of:

```
my_fun_wrong1 <- function(x, y) {
  print("my_fun_wrong1")
  print(x)
  x <- x + y
  print(x)
  res <- UseMethod("fun", x)
  print(res)
  print("END my_fun_wrong1...")
  return(res)
}
x <- c(1, 2)
# Throws: Error in fun.default(x, y = 2) : unused argument (y = 2)
my_fun_wrong1(x, y = 2)

my_fun_wrong2 <- function(x) {
  print("my_fun_wrong2")
  print(x)
  x <- x + y
  print(x)
  res <- UseMethod("fun", x)
  print(res)
  print("END my_fun_wrong2...")
  return(res)
}
x <- c(1, 2)
y = 2
# Does not throw an error, but does not give my expetced result "7": 
my_fun_wrong2(x) # wrong result!?
rm(y)

my_fun_wrong3 <- function(x, ...) {
  print("my_fun_wrong3")
  print(x)
  x <- x + y
  print(x)
  res <- UseMethod("fun", x)
  print(res)
  print("END my_fun_wrong3...")
  return(res)
}
x <- c(1, 2)
# Throws: Error in my_fun_wrong3(x, y = 2) : object 'y' not found
my_fun_wrong3(x, y = 2)
```

---

**Edit** after answer G. Grothendieck: Using `fun.default <- function(x, ...)` I get

Runs after change, but I don't understand the result:

```
my_fun_wrong1(x, y = 2)
[1] "my_fun_wrong1"
[1] 1 2
[1] 3 4         # Ok
[1] "default"
[1] 3           # I excpect 7
```

As before - I don't understand the result:

```
my_fun_wrong2(x) # wrong result!?
[1] "my_fun_wrong2"
[1] 1 2
[1] 3 4        # Ok!
[1] "default"
[1] 3          # 3 + 4 = 7?
```

Still throws an error:

```
my_fun_wrong3(x, y = 2)
[1] "my_fun_wrong3"
[1] 1 2
Error in my_fun_wrong3(x, y = 2) : object 'y' not found
```

---

I think, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34512806/5784831) question is really useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun.default` needs `...` so that the extra argument is matched.

```
fun.default <- function(x, ...) {
  print("default")
  return(x[1] + x[2])
}

x <- c(1, 2)
my_fun_wrong1(x, y = 2)
## [1] "my_fun_wrong1"
## [1] 1 2
## [1] 5 6
## [1] 3
```

Also, any statements after the call to `UseMethod` in the generic will not be evaluated as `UseMethod`does not return so it is pointless to put code after it in the generic.

Furthermore, you can't redefine the arguments to `UseMethod`.  The arguments are passed on as they came in.

Suggest going over the help file `?UseMethod` although admittedly it can be difficult to read.

Regarding the quote from `?UseMethod` that was added to the question, this just means that the methods can access local variables defined in the function calling `UseMethod`.  It does *not* mean that you can redefine arguments. Below `ff.default` refers to the `a` defined in `ff`.

```
a <- 0
ff <- function(x, ...) { a <- 1; UseMethod("ff") }
ff.default <- function(x, ...) a

ff(3)
## [1] 1
```

Comment: See my edit: reduces the errors, but: 1) I would expect `3 4` instead of `5 6`? 2) Why is `res = 3`? I would expect (if accept `5 6`) `11`? 3) My other attempts are wrong? The last attempt still throws an error, the second results in unexpected results - it seems it also ignores `x <- x + y`.

Comment: Sorry, so stupid! I am also blind with respect to questions 2) and 3)?

Comment: Have added to the answer and provided another example.

Comment: Ok, you explained, that I don't understand a lot ;-) I think this is solved and I will ask additional questions, if necessary...

Comment: Although the title is different, it seems, this is the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34512806/5784831)?

Comment: @Christoph, That question was how to get around the fact that you can't modify arguments.  This question seems to assume it is possible and asks why it is not working.